# Flutter-In Switch case , Not rebuild the case widget on changing state in other case widget within the switch case

Tags: flutter

```
    int __respiratoryRate=0;
    
    _buildWidget(
        PatientModel? patientModel,
        cardioVascularWidget,
        BuildContext context,
      ) {
        switch (cardioVascularWidget.key) {
          
          case 'respiratoryRate':
            VitalComponent? respiratoryRate = widget
                .cardiovascularFormModel?.cardiovascularAssessment?.respiratoryRate;
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                CustomInputTextFormField(
                  titleText: respiratoryRate?.title ?? "",
                  hintText: respiratoryRate?.hintText ?? "",
                  trailingInputUnitText: respiratoryRate?.suffixValue ?? "",
                  isTitleRequired: true,
                  isTitleMandatory: true,
                  onEnteredValue: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _respiratoryRate = value == null ? 0 : value.round();
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          case 'heartRate':
            VitalComponent? heartRate =
                

widget.cardiovascularFormModel?.cardiovascularAssessment?.heartRate;
        return CustomInputTextFormField(
          titleText: heartRate?.title ?? "",
          hintText: heartRate?.hintText ?? "",
          trailingInputUnitText: heartRate?.suffixValue ?? "",
          isTitleRequired: true,
          isTitleMandatory: true,
          onEnteredValue: (value) {},
        );
    
      case 'issue':
        Issue? issue =
            widget.cardiovascularFormModel?.cardiovascularAssessment?.issue;
        return Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            TitleMandatoryWidget(isMandatory: false, title: '${issue?.title}'),
            Text('$_respiratoryRate'),
          ],
        );
      case 'nursingDiagnosis':
        NursingDiagnosis? nursingDiagnosis = widget.cardiovascularFormModel
            ?.cardiovascularAssessment?.nursingDiagnosis;
        return Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            TextWidget(
              textValue: '${AppLocalizations.of(context)?.nursingDiagnosis}',
              textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: AppSizeConstants.size8),
            SingleSelectionListGridView(
              title: nursingDiagnosis?.text ?? "",
              isMandatory: nursingDiagnosis?.mandatory ?? false,
              isBoldTitle: false,
              crossCount: nursingDiagnosis?.listview?.columnCount ?? 0,
              onItemSelection: (value) {},
              isOthersSelected: (isSelected) {},
              dataList: nursingDiagnosis?.listview?.values ?? [],
              listGridType: ListGridDisplayType.TEXT_LIST,
            ),
          ],
        );
     case 'evaluation':
        Evaluation? evlnModel = widget
        

        .cardiovascularFormModel?.cardiovascularAssessment?.evaluation;
            return EvaluationWidget(
              onEvaluationChangedValue: (evlnValue) {},
              dataList: evlnModel?.listview?.items ?? [],
              columnCount: evlnModel?.listview?.columnCount ?? 0,
            );
          default:
            return SizedBox();
        }
      }
```

In the switch case, you can see that I have a case `'respiratoryRate'` there is a `textformfield` `onValueChange` i apply a

```
setState(() {
  _respiratoryRate = value == null ? 0 : value.round();
       });
```

and other switch case is `'issue'` is there, i am logging `_respiratoryRate` value but i don't know why my widget is not rebuilding. How can I rebuild the widget?
Could anyone please help me??

Comment: It's hard to debug a block of code. Can you please [edit] your question to include a [mre]? also, please show your `build` widget

Comment: You have only one setstate, are you trying to rebuild in the 'issue' case too? You need more setstates.  Switch statement is not going to execute `respiratoryRate` code too if the value is `issue`. I think you need to log the rate in the parent widget and have the setstate there and call it everytime the value changes.